# flutter build failed after transfering project from windows

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I was working with android studio in windows and everything was working good. I've moved to macos and now when I try to build on android it gives me this error:

```
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"13d2e112-965a-41e4-8c09-495ccdb6309f","id":"2","progressId":null,"message":"Gradle task 'assembleDebug'..."}}]
[  +14 ms] executing: [/Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/api/android/] /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/api/android/gradlew -q -Ptarget=/Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/api/lib/main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
[ +703 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +1 ms] * Where:
[        ] Script '/usr/local/opt/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 602
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:flutterBuildDebug'.
[        ] > java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\\Users\\U728167\\AndroidStudioProjects\\api\\lib\\Screens\\Home\\styles.dart
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 0s
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"13d2e112-965a-41e4-8c09-495ccdb6309f","id":"2","progressId":null,"finished":true}}]
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Strange thing is that it is pointing to an error on my old folder structure (C:\Users\U728167\AndroidStudioProjects\api\lib\Screens\Home\styles.dart)

ps: iOS build is working fine.

edit: after deleting the files/folders in .gitignore, a new error arrives:

```
[  +16 ms] executing: [/Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/android/] /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/android/gradlew -q -Ptarget=/Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/lib/main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
[+3330 ms] D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver
[   +1 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
[        ] > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/6.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/7.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/8.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/9.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/10.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/11.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/12.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/13.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/14.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/15.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/16.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/17.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/18.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/19.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/20.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/21.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/22.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/23.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/24.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/25.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/26.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/27.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/28.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/29.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/30.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/31.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/32.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/33.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/34.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/35.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/36.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/37.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/38.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/39.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/40.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/41.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/42.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/43.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/44.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/45.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/46.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/47.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/48.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/49.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/50.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/51.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/52.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/53.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/60.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/61.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/62.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/63.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/64.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/65.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/66.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/67.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/70.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/72.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/73.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/74.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/75.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/76.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/77.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/78.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/79.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/80.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/81.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/82.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/83.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/85.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/86.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/89.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/91.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/96.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/97.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/98.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/99.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/100.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/101.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/102.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/103.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/104.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/105.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/106.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/107.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/108.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/109.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/110.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/111.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/112.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/113.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/115.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/116.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/117.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/119.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/120.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/121.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/122.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/123.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/124.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/125.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/126.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/127.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/128.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/129.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/130.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/131.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/132.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/133.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/134.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/135.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/137.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/139.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/140.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/142.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/143.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/144.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/145.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/146.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/147.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/148.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/149.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/150.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/151.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/153.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/155.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/156.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/159.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/161.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/162.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/163.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/164.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/165.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/166.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/167.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/169.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/170.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/171.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/172.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/174.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/177.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/178.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/179.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/180.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/181.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/183.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/184.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/185.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/186.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/188.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/189.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/190.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/191.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/193.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/194.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/195.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/196.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/199.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/201.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/202.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/203.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/205.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/206.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/211.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/212.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/213.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/214.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/215.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/216.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/217.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/218.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/220.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/222.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/224.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/225.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/226.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/227.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/229.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/230.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/231.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/232.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/233.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/234.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/235.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/237.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/238.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/239.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/240.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/241.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/242.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/243.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/246.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/247.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/248.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/249.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/250.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/251.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/252.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/253.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/254.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/257.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/258.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/259.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/260.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/262.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/263.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/264.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/265.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/266.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/267.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/268.jar, /Users/u728167/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/269.jar
[        ]   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
[        ]   Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 3s
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"9a38b2a7-5cc7-46d7-890e-dbfee36cea45","id":"2","progressId":null,"finished":true}}]
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you run the command `flutter doctor`?

Answer (score 0):

The `.gitignore` file in your project lists all files that should **not** be included when you copy/move the project to a different machine.

If you use Git to copy the project, this takes care of that automatically.

If you are not using Git, then go through `.gitignore` and just delete the directories and files listed there.

Create a backup before you start with that procedure.

Comment: Did it and now it´s another error: